# VS Code : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pandas-datareader

I followed Microsoft's tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/data-science-tutorial and installed miniconda, I use it's python interpretor, and tried to import the following :

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

However pandas_datareader won't be recognized, but is already installed as it says "requirements already satisfied" when I try to add it from either conda or pip. I don't get why my virtual environnement won't find it after browsing the web for hours, with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all the installations you do will be in base environment and not in the virtual environment.

You'll have to activate the virtual environment in conda and then do a pip list to check if the package is present:

```
conda activate your_env_name
pip list
```

If it's not present, then install it here and try it out. Should work fine.

Comment: it is there : pandas-datareader      0.8.1 :(

Comment: Did you select interpreter in VSCode for this environment?

Comment: I did, I followed each steps of the tutorial, and all the others module weren't problematic. I even tried to uninstall everything related to python, and start over again, with the same results

Comment: Can you add some snippets?

Comment: not sure to understand the question, I added a screenshot to the post

Comment: Restart the VSCode maybe? Ctrl + Shift + P and then `Reload Window`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228766/discussion-between-lazycoder-and-gary-f).

Comment: ok this was really weird, in fact it was because the last pandas was too recent so I had to downgrade it